# Updating and Editing an Entity in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am developing an app in which the user can create a List which will contain a number of Items. My CoreData Model is as follows.

[image]

The code below gets the `list.contains` relationship and store it as an `itemsOnList` Set and then populate a UITableView with each Item in the Set

```
func getItemsOnList(){

    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //fetchRequest to get the List
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "List")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", listName)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    if let fetchResults = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest){
        if fetchResults.count > 0 {
            for listEntity in fetchResults {
                let list = listEntity as! List
                print(list.title as Any)
                itemsOnListSet = list.contains!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the user to be able to change either the name or quantity of the item.

My first way of doing this was since i already have the NSSet of Items i would just change the Item i want and then save the old list.contains with the new one.

Will that be a wise way to do it or is there an easier and simpler way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rename `contains` to `items` so it describes what it is. (edit: also rename `belongsTo` to `list`)

So to access the items linked to a list it will just be `list.items`, much clearer.

Now if you want to edit an item just grab it out of that set and edit away, the relationships don't change. You only need to touch `list.items` again if you wanted to add or remove an item.